# Delphi XE Disconnect or Terminate a datasnap client session

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

We are developing a new Datasnap server (tcp/ip) with Delphi XE and have run into an issue. We do not know when the client disconnects in an abnormal way, ie. the connection is dropped or the client pc is rebooted.

When a client establishes a connection we save it's details in a list as so:

```
TClientInfo = record
  Id: integer;
  Session: TDSSession;
  LastSeen: TDateTime;
end;
...
ClientInfoList: TDictionary<Integer, TClientInfo>;
...
//OnConnect    
ClientInfo.ClientId := ClientId;
ClientInfo.Session := TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession;
ClientInfo.LastSeen := Now();
ClientInfoList.Add(ClientId, ClientInfo);
```

Ideally we would want to iterate throught the ClientInforList and disconnect any client that has not been seen for 30 minutes, but this is where I have a problem.

I have tried to disconnect or terminate the client session as follows without any luck.

```
for i in ServerContainer.ClientInfoList.Keys do
  begin      
    ClientInfo := TClientInfo(ServerContainer.ClientInfoList[i]);
    ClientInfo.Session.Terminate;
  end;
```

Is there a way of doing this in Delphi XE?

Comment: How is `ServerClass.LifeCycle` set?  [`Server`, `Session`, `Invocation`]

Comment: The LifeCycle is set to [Session].

Answer (score 2):

You can't terminate a TCP/IP session from the server side in XE.  Mat DeLong wrote an article that explains how to disconnect a session from the server side when using HTTP in XE, and ends with "**In XE this feature is currently only available with HTTP connections. In XE2, it also works for TCP/IP.**"

- [Server Side Session Management](http://mathewdelong.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/server-side-session-management/)

We had your same problem in XE.  We tried using `LifeCycle := Session` and a timer in the session thread to self terminate it if the user wasn't seen for *x* hours.  But we couldn't terminate the thread from within.  And we couldn't enumerate the thread connections from the main thread.

So we set the `LifeCycle` to [Server] so we could manage the connection list ourselves.  We had to handle all the stuff that happens automatically with a [Session] `LifeCycle`, but at least we could cycle through the connection list and delete connections where the `LastSeen` was more than *x* hours old.

If upgrading to XE2 (now XE3) is an option, it is probably the best option (so you can use the session management methods for [Session] connections).

If you cannot upgrade, then the only way to terminate a session from the server side is to set `LifeCycle` to [Server] and do the session management yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not sure we will be able to use [Server] but I will have a look. We are trying to persuade the powers-that-be to upgrade but it is a slow process.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
And found this solution, like that:

```
for i in ServerContainer.ClientInfoList.Keys do
  begin      
    ClientInfo := TClientInfo(ServerContainer.ClientInfoList[i]);
    TDSSessionManager.Instance.CloseSession(ClientInfo.Session);
  end;
```